# Python how to find a substring in a string and print the whole string containing the substring

Tags: python, string

I am struggling to find a solution to print a string which contains a particular substring. So e.g. I have a string

`mystr = "<tag> name = mon_this_is_monday value = 10 </tag>"`

I want to search for `"mon"` in the string above and print `"mon_this_is_monday"` but not sure how to do it

I tried doing

```
    pattern = re.compile('mon_')
    try:
        match = re.search(pattern, mystr).group(0)
        print(match)
    except AttributeError:
        print('No match')
```

but this this just gives `mon_` as output for match. How do I get the whole string `"mon_this_is_monday"` as output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could try using `re.findall` with the pattern `\b\w*mon\w*\b`:

```
mystr = "<tag> name = mon_this_is_monday value = 10 </tag>"
matches = re.findall(r'\b\w*mon\w*\b', mystr)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['mon_this_is_monday']
```

The regex pattern matches:

```
\b   a word boundary (i.e. the start of the word)
\w*  zero or more word characters (letters, numbers, or underscore)
mon  the literal text 'mon'
\w*  zero or more word characters, again
\b   another word boundary (the end of the word)
```

Comment: Great! Could you please elaborate how did you come up with the pattern? Great! also, if I want to print the value ("10") how can I do that?

Comment: I added an explanation of the regex pattern, but for your value requirement, I will leave it to you to figure out how to apply my answer to it (or ask another question later).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks

Comment: Positive lookahead may also work `re.findall(r'(?=(mon\_\S*))', mystr)`

Answer (score 3):

`print([string for string in mystr.split(" ") if "mon" in string])`

Answer (score 0):

you can also do a search on regex

```
import re


mystr = "<tag> name = mon_this_is_monday value = 10 </tag>"

abc = re.search(r"\b(\w*mon\w*)\b",mystr)

print(abc.group(0))
```